# How can I tell what -j option was provided to make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In [Racket](http://racket-lang.org)'s build system, we have a build step that invokes a program that can run several parallel tasks at once.  Since this is invoked from `make`, it would be nice to respect the `-j` option that `make` was originally invoked with.

However, as far as I can tell, there's no way to get the value of the `-j` option from inside the `Makefile`, or even as an environment variable in the programs that `make` invokes.

Is there a way to get this value, or the command line that `make` was invoked with, or something similar that would have the relevant information?  It would be ok to have this only work in GNU make.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the `-j` option to allow Make itself to manage multiple parallel tracks of dependency resolution?  So your build system is already parallelised, without needing to explicitly parallelise the individual applications involved.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, large portions of the build system are managed using a pretty straightforward use of make, where `-j` is the appropriate tool.  Then there's a stage where a Racket program is invoked, and it internally can run in parallel.  We'd like to let the user control these two places where parallel tasks are spawned with a single point of control.

Also, the overall build is kicked off with a call to `make`, so `-j` is the easiest way to specify the desired parallelism.

Comment: Normally, `$(MAKEFLAGS)` would provide you this kind of information. Have you tried playing around with that one?

Comment: @Reinier, sadly `$(MAKEFLAGS)` gets a preprocessed version of the flags, which is identical for all `-j` options greater than 1.  I'll add an answer to the question to that effect, but it's not a solution.

Comment: That is weird. If information is lost in the preprocessed version of the flags, then that looks like a bug in `make` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `make 4.2.1` finally they got `MAKEFLAGS` right. That is, you can have in your Makefile a target

```
opts:
    @echo $(MAKEFLAGS)
```

and making it will tell you the value of `-j` parameter right.

```
$ make -j10 opts
-j10 --jobserver-auth=3,4
```

(In `make 4.1` it is still broken). Needless to say, instead of `echo`  you can invoke a script doing proper parsing of `MAKEFLAGS`

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer concerns `make` version 3.82 and earlier. For a better answer as of version 4.2, see the answer by Dima Pasechnik.

---

You can not tell what -j option was provided to make. Information about the number of jobs is not accessible in the regular way from make or its sub-processes, according to the following quote:

> The top make and all its sub-make processes use a pipe to communicate with
>   each other to ensure that no more than N jobs are started across all makes.

(taken from the file called NEWS in the make 3.82 source code tree)

The top make process acts as a job server, handing out tokens to the sub-make processes via the pipe. It seems to be your goal to do your own parallel processing and still honor the indicated maximum number of simultaneous jobs as provided to `make`. In order to achieve that, you would somehow have to insert yourself into the communication via that pipe. However, this is an unnamed pipe and as far as I can see, there is no way for your own process to join the job-server mechanism.

By the way, the "preprocessed version of the flags" that you mention contain the expression `--jobserver-fds=3,4` which is used to communicate information about the endpoints of the pipe between the make processes. This exposes a little bit of what is going on under the hood...

Comment: Well, that wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but it does seem to be the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are really eager to get information about the desired number of jobs and active number of make processes, I guess you could always do a `ps -ef`, `grep` for `make` and parse the input -- including the tree of pids and child-pids. That way, you can find the value of `-j` as well as the number of active jobs. You will still not be able to completely participate in the job-sever process though. Good luck :-)