# make -jXXX : how can I get XXX

Tags: makefile, gnu-parallel

I have a parallel test suite (perl prove -j XXX).   If a user types make -j 8 all, I'd like the test suite to be run with the same parameter: prove -j XXX t.   If not, then I'd like it to be run single-threaded.   Since I know the test suite is top level and depends on all of the binary targets, I'd like to, very simply, pass-through the user's specified parallel argument.

Is there something in gnu make that allows for getting the command-line arguments used to run make?  Or will the user have to do something like: make -j 8 PLL=8 all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what -j option was provided to make](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10898528/1380680)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what -j4 value is used to invoke make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110751/what-j4-value-is-used-to-invoke-make)

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual `-j` is passed down to some sub-makes (via `MAKEFLAGS`) in some circumstances, but not most and is not (apparently) present in `MAKEFLAGS` in the toplevel make. So I don't see any way to get this information unfortunately.

You could, however, have the user pass the value only through a variable assignment `PLL=8` and add it to `MAKEFLAGS` yourself manually (`MAKEFLAGS += -j$(PLL)`) with appropriate guarding for only doing that in the toplevel makefile and only when some other value of `-j` isn't in `MAKEFLAGS` (in case that can actually happen somehow). I believe this will work correctly as far as make jobserver behaviour is concerned.