# what -j4 value is used to invoke make?

Tags: makefile

How can I figure out, from a make rule, what is the value of the make -j argument ? Is there something like an environment variable ? For instance if I run:

```
make -j4 something
```

I would like the `something` rule to display `4`. The [GNU make manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion) suggests communication between the parent make and its children which could probably be used to extract this information. But how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this isn't at all easy actually.

John Graham-Cunning wrote an entire blog post about it [here](http://blog.jgc.org/2015/03/gnu-make-insanity-finding-value-of-j.html).

Comment: This is a great post ! I'll find another way though, I don't want to end up in a mental institution :-)

Comment: What is your actual goal here?

Comment: I want to fail if ulimit is likely to not be enough for the given -jX. Roughly X * 1024 open files needed, that kind of thing.

Comment: The last time someone asked a question like this I believe I suggested a wrapper script that does that checking.

Comment: the problem is that users who need this safeguard cannot be conveniently instructed to use something other than make -jX. It's a good idea though.

Comment: Force a sentinel value to be defined on the make command line for the make to work and set it in the script. That obviously won't stop anyone who bothers to look from figuring the trick out and just doing it themselves but the naive attempt to run make will fail (with an instructive message about using the setup wrapper script). =)